# Generating random numbers non-repeating recursively in C

Tags: c

I'm making BINGO and I need to generate each space with a random number specified below without having duplicates. So I'm going each row at a time because of letter-number combo min/max cap (B: 1-15, I: 16-30, N: 31-45, G: 46-60, O: 61-75). It seems the best way to do this is to have a recursive function. I believe that the following function is correct except for the fact that i is not increasing. How would I go about fixing this so I don't make the same or similar mistake in the future?

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int bMin = 1, bMax = 15;
    int i = 0;
    int B1[5] = {0};
    initializeCard(B1, bMin, bMax, i);

    // print value of B1 to make sure function correctly executed
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", B1[i]);
    }
}

void initializeCard(int row[5], int min, int max, int i) {
    row[i] = rand() % ((max + 1) - min) + min;

    int temp;
    for (temp = i; temp >= 0; temp--) {
        if (row[i] == row[temp]) {
            initializeCard(row, min, max, i);
        }
    }

    if (i < 5) {
        i++;
        initializeCard(row, min, max, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider whether you'd do better creating an array with all the possible letter/number combinations in a fixed order that's easy to verify, and then use a Fisher-Yates shuffle on that array to generate a random permutation of the data.  The fact that each entry in the array is unique ensures there are no duplicates in the shuffled data, and a good Fisher-Yates shuffle ensures each permutation is equi-probable.

Comment: Don't use recursion. It feels really sexy but its also a really bad idea, especially if you ever get into embedded programming where stack sizes are limited. In this case, as Osiris points out, you get runaway recursion so no matter how much memory you have and how big your stack is allowed to grow, at some point the stack will overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one big problem in your initialize function:

```
for (temp = i; temp >= 0; temp--)
{
    if (row[i] == row[temp])
    {
        initializeCard(row, min, max, i);
    }
}
```

Since you start with `temp = i`, `row[i] == row[temp]` is always true, so there is no way to break the recursion. You should start from `temp = i-1`:

```
for (temp = i-1; temp >= 0; temp--)
```

I also cleaned the function a little bit up:

```
void initializeCard(int row[5], int min, int max, int i)
{
    row[i] = rand() % ((max + 1) - min) + min;

    int temp;
    for (temp = i-1; temp >= 0; temp--) //Do not check i itself
    {
        if (row[i] == row[temp])
        {
            initializeCard(row, min, max, i);
            return; //No need to continue this function
        }
    }

    i++; //Increment before checking, otherwise it is executed with i=5 which is out of bounds
    if (i < 5)
    {
        initializeCard(row, min, max, i);
    }
}
```

Of course the better approach would be to not try again if a duplicate was found, instead eliminate the possibility that you can create a duplicate. For example write all possible numbers in one array and delete the chosen one every time.